# lxml xpath exponential performance behavior

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to use xpath to query a large html with multiple tables and only extract a few tables that contain a specific pattern in one of the cells. I'm running into time related challenges.

I've tried to minimize by issue as much as possible.

code setup: - creates 10 (300x15) tables with random values between 0-100

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, (300, 15)), columns=[f"Col-{i}" for i in range(15)]) for k in range(10)]
html_strings = [df.to_html() for df in dataframes]
combined_html = '\n'.join(html_strings)
source_html = f'<html><body>{combined_html}</body></html>'
```

code execution: I want to extract all tables that have the value "80" in them (in this case it will be all 10 tables)

```py
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(source_html.encode())

PAT = '80' # this should result in returning all 10 tables as 80 will definitely be there in all of them (pandas index)

# method 1: query directly using xpath - this takes a long time to run - and this seems to exhibit exponential time behavior
xpath_query = "//table//*[text() = '{PAT}']/ancestor::table"
tables = root.xpath(xpath_query)

# method 2: this runs in under a second. first get all the tables and then run the same xpath expression within the table context
all_tables = root.xpath('//table')
table_xpath_individual = ".//*[text() = '{PAT}']/ancestor::table"
selected_tables = [table for table in all_tables if table.xpath(table_xpath_individual)]
```

method 1 takes 40-50s to finish
method 2 takes <1s

I'm not sure whether it's the xpath expression in method 1 that's problematic or it's an lxml issue here. I've switched to using method 2 for now - but unsure whether it's a 100% equivalent behavior

Comment: Note that lxml uses libxml2 to process XPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is relevant (but I suspect so). You can simplify these XPaths by eliminating the `//*` step and the trailing `/ancestor::table` step.

```xml
//table[descendant::text() = '{PAT}']
```

Note that in your problematic XPath, for each table you will find *every* descendant element whose text is `80` (there might be many within a table) and for each one, return *all* of that element's  `table` ancestors (again, because in theory there might be more than one if you had a table containing a table, the XPath processor is going to have to laboriously traverse all those `ancestor` paths). That will return a potentially large number of results which the XPath processor will then have to deduplicate, so that it doesn't return multiple instances of any given `table` (an XPath 1.0 nodeset is guaranteed not to contain duplicates).

Comment: Thanks for the response. 2 questions: 1) how would this work if I had to use `contains` instead of an equality? the variants I've tried return no results. 2) These tables are all at the top level - so the ancestor traversal should be equivalent in both cases? unless i'm misunderstanding things here

Comment: Re your 2nd comment. Yes the paths are _logically_ equivalent, in that they will produce the same result, but compare the two procedures: (1): search for tables, then for each table, search for a descendant text node that matches a pattern (search can stop after finding 1 matching text node), vs (2) searching for tables, then for each table search for all descendant text nodes that match a pattern, then search for the same ancestor tables, and eliminate duplicate tables from that final result. It's much more work, and this is likely why you've found the run time unacceptable.

Comment: If the tables are all the top level, then there's no need to start the XPath with //table; you can optimize that part of the traversal by using /html/body/table; that will save the time spent searching fruitlessly for nested tables. If you want to use the `contains` function instead of string equality, your XPath would be: `/html/body/table[descendant::text()[contains(., 'whatever')]]`

Comment: great - thank you so much for those comments!